# Defining the pre-image topology for $f:A\rightarrow B$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces

> Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function from a set $A$ to a topology
>   $(B,\tau)$.
>
> Then I can define a subbase on $A$ simply by giving $f[A]\subset B$
>   the subspace topology inherited from $B$ and defining the inverse
>   image of each open set in $f[A]$ to be open in $A$.  Thus let
>   $(A,f^{-1}\tau)$ be the topology on $A$ generated by this subbase.

**Question 1:** Is this subbase actually a topology?  I think probably so but I'd prefer to just have my intuition verified rather than going through the details myself.

**Question 2:** Is the quotient topology $A/\sim$ given by the relation $x\equiv y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$ homeomorphic to $B$?  I'm almost certain this is true.

**Question 3:** If we assume $f[A]$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $A/\sim$ is a manifold with a single chart and is thus smooth, correct?

**Question 4:** So assuming question 2 is true, that means that since $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality, I could in theory put a compact topology on the set $\mathbb{R}$, or a non-compact topology on the set $[0,1]$, correct?

Comment: @LeeMosher $A=f^{-1}(B)$, where $B$ must be open for it to have a topology so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Question 1 gets you a close vote: if you aren't interested in the details, why should anyone else bother to verify them for you?

Comment: @Rob Arthan well I imagine most people with expertise in topology (probably you) could just tell me off hand that it's true, it's not like they'd have to do the proof themselves.  They're certainly welcome to give me the details if they wish, but I'm not requesting them.  Sometimes you just want to verify your intuition without laboring through the details of every single potential fact you come across.  If I had access to people in real life with this knowledge I'd just ask them, but since I don't Math.SE is all I have so if you want to be an asshole and close the question then that's on you.

Comment: But why do you care about the answer if you're not interested in the details? The distinction between subbase and a base is an important technical detail. (Like the distinction between people who call others  "assholes" and people who are worth giving assistance to.) Your questions 2, 3 and 4 also read like an enquiry to a homework-solution service, which is not what MSE is for.

Comment: Because I doubt the details of the proof are in this case particularly enlightening.  I put it in the format I did to make it easy on the reader, but it appears that approach has backfired and made it look like a homework question, either way if you don't want to answer it then you've down voted it and voted to close and done everything in your power to make it so others won't answer so now why don't you kindly go away.

Comment: Actually, I didn't downvote your question. I just voted to close it (because I don't approve of the anonymity of downvoting, but do think that asking a question phrased as "I need you to help because I can't be bothered to work through the details myself" is not appropriate on MSE). If you show some indication you've done some work on these questions, then you're in with a chance of getting useful answers.

Comment: except clearly I have done work and put considerable thought into formulating what I wrote (e.g. I wrote subbase and not base for a reason).  My understanding was that Math.SE was a place to learn about mathematics above and beyond just a place where you get help when you're stuck on a proof, maybe I'm wrong about that.  Not every one has the time to do a proof for everything they want to know.

Comment: Read what you write: "I'd prefer to just have my intuition verified rather than going through the details myself" is saying "please do my work for me".

Comment: your continued harping on one silly little sentence fragment I made off-hand is ridiculous, like I said I bet you know the answer to question 1 without having to do any work.

Comment: So edit your question to make it worth answering!